# Gettng exception while using findBy using JPARepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables Employee and Address. Each have primary key **sequence_id** and **address_Id**  which is generated through sequence.

**Employee Class:**

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sequence_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emp_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "emp_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "emp_seq")
    private Long sequenceId;

    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private String empId;

    @Column(name = "joiningDate")
    private Date businessDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}
```

**Address Class**

public class Address {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "address_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "address_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "address_seq")
private Long addressID;

@Column(name = "street")
private String street;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Employee employee;
```

}

I am using JPARepository to save both entities. here is my main class.

```
Employee e = Employee.builder().businessDate(new Date())
        .empId("thinkerId").build();
Address a = Address.builder().street("32nd Street")
        .employee(e).build();
e.setAddress(a);
empRepository.save(e);
```

Code runs successfully and save both into address and employee table.

But it failed while usig findAll() / findById method?

```
Optional<Employeee> emp = employeeRepository.findById(23l); //**FAILING**
```

**Error --**

```
[2022.02.08 09:08:13:401] [http-nio-8997-exec-2] [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper] [WARN ] - SQL Error: 1722, SQLState: 42000
[2022.02.08 09:08:13:403] [http-nio-8997-exec-2] [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper] [ERROR] - ORA-01722: invalid number

[2022.02.08 09:08:13:430] [http-nio-8997-exec-2] [o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener] [INFO ] - HHH000327: Error performing load command
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

While using findAll() method, I got below error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.msci.rt.monitoring.entity.Employee.empId] by reflection for persistent property [com.msci.rt.monitoring.entity.Employee#empId] :
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String Employee.emp_ID] by reflection for persistent property [empId] : 22
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Employee.empId to null value
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
```

How can i get **"thinkerId"** as value in Address table?

Thank you.

Comment: Pls provide employeeRepository class thx

Comment: @Oliver, it is a empty class which extends JPARepository.

Comment: `Each have primary key empId and addressId` ... no they don't.  The primary key for employee is `sequence_id`, because this field bears the `@Id` annotation.

Comment: Sorry @Tim, Made a mistake in my question. That's true, sequence_id is the PK. But i want to join thru emp_id.  Making a correction in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message from Hibernate seems to be saying that the database is expecting a number somewhere, but instead is getting something else, possibly a string.  If you examine your `Employee` entity class, you'll notice that you have defined the join column `emp_id` to be a string.  However the primary key field there is called `sequence_id`.  I suggest making the PK column the join field.  Use this version:

```java
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emp_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "emp_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "emp_seq")
    private Long empId;

    @Column(name = "joiningDate")
    private Date businessDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}
```

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number
Cause: You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: This ORA-01722 is showing in stack trace so probably due to this issue

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa Look at the join annotation on the other entity: `@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")` ... it was clearly referencing a _string_ column.  My answer should fix this problem (though admittedly, there may still be other problems).

Comment: @Tim , Thanks for your answer, Actually I want to join using emp_id (String) only.  Is it not possible? I have created a sequence as a PK as it maintain the order employee are added. When i see emp_id in other tables , it makes more sense to me instead of just a number. Can it be done?

Comment: @Tim I have added another stacktrace while calling findAll() method which seems to relate as yours.